# What do the two German ladies discuss in The Darjeeling Limited?

Tags: screenplay, the-darjeeling-limited

In *The Darjeeling Limited*, there are two German ladies having a frantic conversation on the train that serves to distract the protagonists. What are they saying? A link to a detailed transcript would be ideal. I looked but couldn't find one.

It happens roughly from 10:20 to 11:20

Comment: Can you share a timeline around when did the German ladies appear in the movie?  That will be helpful in finding it in a script.

Comment: Nah I couldn't find it in a script either.

Comment: @Spectra The IMDb thing you cited was more than I was anticipating getting so it'll probably do. So thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0838221/faq):

> **What are the German ladies arguing about?**
> Something about that they should have two set of keys for each. The
> other answers "That's quite easy." The scene then returns to the
> brothers. As their voices get louder, one lady is telling the other
> that her memory is bad, and the other lady responds that the first
> lady is the one who doesn't hear well, that she uses a hearing
> apparatus, and then something about how 'naturally that's what i
> said'. It's a bit hard to piece together. In the part where they
> whisper to each other when the brothers take out all their
> medications, they are saying, "Did you see what they have on the
> table?"